# iPad - Transferring files from the "Files" app to the "Photos" app

Tags: ipad, photos.app, file-transfer, airdrop, files.app

I would like to transfer all the files in a particular album from the "Files" app to the "Photos" app on my iPad. I used Airdrop from my MacBook to transfer several video and image files to my iPad. I confirmed the files were sent by viewing some of them. I'm also starting to use Kinemaster for video editing on the iPad. It looks like when I select the "Video" tab and "All" from the "Albums" section of Kinemaster, it only allows me to access albums that were created using the "Photos" app.

There was no access to anything I had in the "Files" app. That would lead me to assume that if I transferred the album of the videos and images from the "Files" app into the "Photos" app, Kinemaster will have access to them. I selected all of the images and videos in "Files" and tapped "Share", but did not see "Photos" as a target app in the list. I even tapped the "More" dots button but "Photos" was not listed as a target either.

The attached screen shots show the choices the iPad gives in the "Sharing" screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no need to add the solution to the question, it actually is rather confusing for future visitors. Upvote useful answers, accept the one which was most useful (and maybe edit it with details if they are important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is do this on your Mac.

Open Photos and then import the photos (from the menu File->Import)

Photos will then sync the photographs over to your iPad

There is one possible downside - you have to have a large enough iCloud subscription to hold the photos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In a while I will see if I can use that method to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the sharing sheet of a picture you should see a "Save picture" entry beneath the second row of icons (you may need to drag the sharing sheet upwards to see it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added screen shots from the sharing sheet but didn't see "Save picture" in the list.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen This is not the sharing sheet, this is the selection you get when you tap on the three dots for "More". Tap on "Done" and scroll down.